# MRUnit test giving NULLPOINTER exception while writing to HDFS using MULTIPLEOUTPUTS

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, mrunit

I currently have a mapReduce program that send data to hdfs with different file name.So in my reducer I am using MultipleOutputs to write to different files in HDFS (Full Reducer code below).

I would like to test my code using mrunit and below is my test method.

```
@Test
public void reducerMRUnit() throws IOException{

    String output="";
    ArrayList<Text> list = new ArrayList<Text>(0);
    list.add(new Text(""));

    reduceDriver.withInput(new Text(""), list);

    reduceDriver.withPathOutput(new Text(output),NullWritable.get(),"");


    reduceDriver.runTest();
}
```

But, when I run this test it giving me NPE.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:104)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.getDefaultWorkFile(FileOutputFormat.java:286)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:129)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs.getRecordWriter(MultipleOutputs.java:476)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs.write(MultipleOutputs.java:456)
at org.clinical3PO.learn.fasta.ArffToFastAReducer.reduce(ArffToFastAReducer.java:127)
at org.clinical3PO.learn.fasta.ArffToFastAReducer.reduce(ArffToFastAReducer.java:1)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.mapreduce.ReduceDriver.run(ReduceDriver.java:265)
at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.TestDriver.runTest(TestDriver.java:640)
at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.TestDriver.runTest(TestDriver.java:627)
at org.clinical3PO.learn.fasta.MRUnitTest.ArffToFastAReducerMRUnitTest.reducerMRUnit(ArffToFastAReducerMRUnitTest.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Reducer code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs;

public class AReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, NullWritable>{
    private MultipleOutputs<Text, NullWritable> mos = null;

    @Override
    public void setup(Context context) throws IOException {
        mos = new MultipleOutputs<Text, NullWritable>(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        mos = new MultipleOutputs<Text, NullWritable>(context);
        mos.write(key, value, "filename");
    }

    @Override
    public void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        mos.close();
    }
}
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MRUnit currently has a known issue, which is not well documented, that testing `MultipleOutputs` requires running the test with `PowerMockRunner` and a `PrepareForTest` annotation applied to mock the reducer class.  JIRA issues [MRUNIT-13](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRUNIT-13) and [MRUNIT-213](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRUNIT-213) contain detailed discussion of this.  MRUNIT-213 is still unresolved/unfixed.

Adding PowerMock to the project then triggers some further challenges in lining up the right compatible versions of Mockito and PowerMock.  The documentation on [Using PowerMock with Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13) covers which versions are compatible.

I tried making these changes to your sample.  That got past the `NullPointerException`, but then I ran into one final problem.  The expected path output declared in the test did not match up with the `"filename"` path used by the reducer code.  I changed the expected path output to get the test completely passing.

Here is my final result: a fully working project with your sample test.  Enjoy!

## pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-mrunit</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Test MRUnit</name>
    <description>Test MRUnit</description>
    <properties>
        <hadoop.version>2.7.1</hadoop.version>
        <powermock.version>1.6.4</powermock.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

## src/main/java/AReducer.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs;

public class AReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, NullWritable>{
    private MultipleOutputs<Text, NullWritable> mos = null;

    @Override
    public void setup(Context context) throws IOException {
        mos = new MultipleOutputs<Text, NullWritable>(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        mos.write(key, NullWritable.get(), "filename");
    }

    @Override
    public void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        mos.close();
    }
}
```

## src/test/java/TestAReducer.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.mapreduce.ReduceDriver;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(AReducer.class)
public class TestAReducer {

    @Test
    public void reducerMRUnit() throws IOException{
        ReduceDriver reduceDriver = new ReduceDriver(new AReducer());
        String output = "";
        ArrayList<Text> list = new ArrayList<Text>(0);
        list.add(new Text(""));
        reduceDriver.withInput(new Text(""), list);
        reduceDriver.withPathOutput(new Text(output), NullWritable.get(), "filename");
        reduceDriver.runTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Chris Nauroth... It resolved the NullPointerException but as you said it giving mismatch of outputs (Assertion Error).Even after I placing the same file path as the reducer code giving.